# Using Make with force snippet to override other file

Tags: makefile

I've been trying to get a makefile, a, to include another makefile, b, if the target specified is not found in file a. I'm using [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Overriding-Makefiles.html) snippet to try and achieve this, but from echos I've put into the file I can see that makefile b is being accessed even when the target is found in a and run.

The snippet I'm using from the link above is:

```
foo:
        frobnicate > foo

%: force
        @echo "No target found locally, running default makefile"
        @$(MAKE) -f Makefile $@
force: ;
```

Specifically I'm getting "Nothing to be done" outputs when makefile b is being used, and makefile a is behaving as expected. This is shown below:

```
$ make all  # all target appears in both make files
No target found locally, running default makefile
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/currdir' # (b)
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `Makefile'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/currdir'
 Local all # (a)
```

Is there a better way to be doing this?

addition: After adding another echo to the % rule, I've found that $@ is "Makefile", when it should be the target trying to be built.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question based on the example you gave; there is no "a" or "b" in that example, just one `Makefile`.

However, the behavior you're seeing is due to GNU make's [re-making makefiles](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Remaking-Makefiles.html) capability.  When you create match-anything pattern rules as you've done, you have to consider that every single target or prerequisite that make wants to build will match that rule.  That's a large burden.

You can avoid having remade makefiles match by creating explicit rules for them, such as:

```
Makefile: ;
```